# Передача Cookies из HttpWebResponse в WebBrowser

Tags: c#, cookie, webbrowser

Есть код

```
Uri u1= new Uri(ip);
CookieContainer cookie; 
HttpWebRequest request3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request3.CookieContainer = cookie;
request3.Method = "POST"; 
byte[] EncodedPostParams3 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(secondStepForm3);
request3.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams3.Length;
request3.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams3, 0, EncodedPostParams3.Length);
request3.GetRequestStream().Close();
result = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();
result.Cookies = request3.CookieContainer.GetCookies(request3.RequestUri);
foreach (Cookie c in result.Cookies)
{
  cookie.Add(u1,c);
  st = st +c.ToString() + ";";             //Строка куки для передачи
}
```

Он отправляет `POST` запрос аутентификации с логином и паролем. Получаем `CookieContainer cookie`. Теперь при создании нового `HttpWebRequest` достаточно указать свойство `CookieContainer` и получать данные.

```
HttpWebRequest request4 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url+"?"+zapros);
request4.CookieContainer = cookie;
request4.Method = "GET";
```

Эта часть работает, с помощью GET запросов получаю страницы и выбираю нужные ссылки. По полученной ссылке нужно показать страницу в браузере. Создаю объект `WebBrowser` и пытаюсь передать туда `cookie`.

```
WebBrowser br= new WebBrowser();
br.Document.Cookie=st;
br.Navigate(Url);
```

Выкидывает на страницу аутентификации.

Comment: Странная у вас задача. Почему бы не просто открыть исходный POST-URL в WebBrowser'е?

Comment: Мне в основном нужны данные **HTTPRequest**, чтобы их парсить и выбирать нужное. 
Но иногда придестя открывать некоторые страницы. Можно конечно и 2 раза  аутентификацию делать, но это как-то не правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Исользуйте этот класс:

```
    public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer container)
        {
            this._container = container;
        }

        private readonly CookieContainer _container = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest r = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            var request = r as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.CookieContainer = _container;
            }
            return r;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);
            ReadCookies(response);
            return response;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            ReadCookies(response);
            return response;
        }

        private void ReadCookies(WebResponse r)
        {
            var response = r as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response != null)
            {
                CookieCollection cookies = response.Cookies;
                _container.Add(cookies);
            }
        }
    }
```